# How to open system monitor easily?

Tags: shortcut-keys, system-monitor

As stated above, is there a command to open system monitor?

Comment: Why don't you lock the System Monitor in Unity Launcher. That will be easy.

Comment: `snap install gnome-system-monitor`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Run in terminal,

```
gnome-system-monitor
```

This would open system monitor.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gnome-system-monitor` https://vitux.com/how-to-install-and-use-task-manager-system-monitor-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 45):

### GNOME System Monitor

Run the system monitor from *Terminal* by typing: `gnome-system-monitor`

Alternatively, run this command by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (or <kbd>Super</kbd>, also known as "Windows key") and typing `gnome-system-monitor`

### Keyboard shortcut

You can add a custom keyboard command using the following steps:

1. Go to **System Settings**
2. Click **Keyboard**
3. Open the **Shortcuts** tab
4. Click the "**+**" symbol near the bottom of the window
5. Give your command a **title**. E.g. *System Monitor*
6. In the **Command** field, enter `gnome-system-monitor`
7. Click **Apply**
8. Click **Disabled** on your newly created shortcut
9. Enter the key combination you want for your shortcut. E.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

**Note:** on Ubuntu 14.10, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is already in use, but can be overridden.

Comment: For those looking to mimic Windows, bind System Monitor to `Ctrl + Shift + Esc`, which is the shortcut to open Task Manager directly.

Comment: FTR: in Gnome 40.3 instead of a + there's a list of shortcuts groups, and one of them says something like "additional shortcuts" *(depending on localization)*, it serves as a placeholder for user shortcuts, so you can add a custom one in it.

Answer (score 6):

Why open the terminal at all? You are opening an extra application, which you may not be able to close without closing the System Monitor, to open something that can be done with some keystrokes: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> then type *gnome-system-monitor*. That's the most hassle free.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Keyboard Shortcut to easily open **System Monitor**.

Type Keyboard in Unity Dash, this will open Keyboard Settings. Click on **Shortcuts**, select **Custom Shortcuts**, click on add button. This will open a window.

Type any Name **System Monitor** and Command `gnome-system-monitor`, apply.

Now click on disabled and choose any Keyboard shortcut like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. This will easily open System Monitor when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

To open the terminal press below key :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Then type this command on terminal:

```
$ gnome-system-monitor
```

Right click on process and click on Kill process.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04

- Uninstall system monitor:

**`sudo snap remove gnome-system-monitor`**

- Install system monitor with apt:

**`sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor`**

Comment: This is clearly not what the Question is about.