# What is the difference between the system console the linux console and the virtual console?

Tags: tty

so there are three different articles on wikipedia describing what seems to be to be the same thing, i found this question asked previously

[What is the difference between Terminal, Console, Shell, and Command Line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506510/what-is-the-difference-between-terminal-console-shell-and-command-line)

but i'm creating new this question because i understand what the command line interface is, i understand what the shell is, i understand what the physical computer terminal is.

but what i don't understand what the difference is between the system console the linux console and the virtual console, i checked wikipedia and there are 3 different articles seemingly describing the same, or semi same thing.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_console
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_console
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console

so i just wanted to ask this question and see what people think, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Terminal, Console, Shell, and Command Line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506510/what-is-the-difference-between-terminal-console-shell-and-command-line) and [Ubuntu System Monitor](https://askubuntu.com/q/544666/)

Comment: no, it does not answer my question, in fact, i referenced that post in my post that it does not answer my question, and that my question is different, thanks.

Comment: The built-in system console application in Ubuntu is the System Monitor. I posted a link to a 2nd duplicate question about the Ubuntu System Monitor to cover all three topics in this question which is too broad for the 1st link to cover by itself and it also needs focus.

Comment: i don't know what a system monitor is, and i don't know what you mean.

Comment: The second link in his first comment.

Comment: Link to an image of the built-in System Monitor application in the Dash: https://www.hecticgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Opening-system-monitor-from-Dash-in-Ubuntu.jpg. Click the System Monitor icon in the Dash to open the System Monitor. I suppose you could say that by system console you intended it to be something else, but if so it's unclear what this "something else" is.

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about.